# How can I program a function in R to decompose any integer into a power of 2 plus some number?

Tags: r

I would like to program a function in R to allow me to decompose any integer n into n=2^j+k where j>=0 and 0<= k <2^j. I have thought about using the modulus operation, but am failing to get a k that is less than 2^j. Would anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For values of `n > 0` you could try this function:

```
pow2_decompose <- function(n) {
  j <- trunc(log2(n))
  k <- n - 2**j
  return(list(j,k))
}
```

[Example:](https://ideone.com/JJ6JUU)

```
n <- 1289
j <- pow2_decompose(n)[[1]]
k <- pow2_decompose(n)[[2]]
cat(j,k,"\n")
#10 265 
identical(2**j + k, n)
#[1] TRUE
```